# Splitting dataframe

Tags: scala, parsing

How would you split a dataframe in scala?

```
{code}---

{code}---
```

Comment: Is better to provide the output you are looking for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How we can parse logs in Spark using Dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57428503/how-we-can-parse-logs-in-spark-using-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should use the RDD API to deal with unstructured data.

Reading a textFile returns you an `RDD[String]` which can be mapped with a pure scala function for transformation (structuration) purpose.

Comment: It's an apache log. There is a fixed structure.

Comment: It's a string containing structured data representation, so it's not structured yet (dataframe api is designed for pre-structured data)

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("test").master("local[2]").getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._

val testDf = Seq("66.249.69.97 - - [24/Sep/2014:22:25:44 +0000] \"GET /071300/242153 HTTP/1.1\" 404 514 \"-\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)\"").toDF

testDf.map(r => {

  val splittedString = r.getString(0).split("-")

  (splittedString(0), splittedString(1), splittedString(2), splittedString(3))

}).show
```

Result:

[image]